# Is it possible to filter GIS SE to QGIS?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

Is it possible to filter GIS SE to only those questions that are specific to QGIS?

In the past 2 days I've only just started evaluating QGIS and this place; [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Is the only option / work around, for example, of not having such a thing as QGIS GIS SE, to browse the [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=qgis%20site=gis.stackexchange.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) for the term QGIS? or to be solely reliant on those tagged needles in the haystack? Surprisingly there were only [two](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis).

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "there were only two". Almost all QGIS questions are tagged and the search returns a long list.

Comment: You must be on the Featured tab which currently has only 2 - change it to Unanswered  and you should see 889 ... and if you include all the answered ones it is many thousands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the search box on upper right corner of gis.se main webpage and type:

```
[qgis]
```

All questions tagged with QGIS will come up.

Then, you have options to filter questions tagged with QGIS, such as the newest ones, the questions which have the highest score (upvote - downvote) and etc.

As suggested by whuber you also may also search only questions or answers, doing the following:

```
[qgis] is:question
[qgis] is:answer
```

Typing the word `qgis` without brackets will bring all threads that mentions QGIS with or without [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) tag associated.

The picture below shows today we have 4120 threads labeled with QGIS.

[image]

For more information about the Stack Exchange search engine, see this thread:

[A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHvLC.jpg)

Also, see both GeoKevin's and Mapperz's answer for other possible searching approaches.

Comment: +1. This search can be improved. First, I recommend not limiting it to the "QGIS" tag, because some QGIS questions do not have that tag.  Second, to find just *questions*, include the "is:question" criterion.  Follow [this link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=qgis+is%3Aquestion) to see the results.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to find only QGIS-related questions is to click the Tags tab (under the title on the main page), then click the [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) tag. Note that you may have to type qgis in the search box on that page before the tag is visible. Clicking the tag filters the questions.

You could also search for `[qgis]` (as Andre Silva answered and underdark commented) in the top menu bar on the main page.

Regardless of how you searched for [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) questions, **make sure you are not on the Featured tab**, which currently only shows two questions (as PolyGeo mentioned). I recommend checking the Newest, Active, and Unanswered tabs to see most/all QGIS questions.

Comment: I did not see your answer before posting mine. Yet, I think they are more complementary than substitutes.

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer to reference yours.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use the **Stack Exchange Data Explorer** to do custom queries across Stack Exchange sites.

http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/queries

This query can be  '**forked**' and can be modified to your specific requirements.

http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/3978/most-popular-stackoverflow-tags-in-may-2010

Example Only:

```
    -- Most popular StackOverflow tags in May 2010

select 
       num.TagName as Tag,
       row_number() over (order by rate.Rate desc) as MayRank,
       row_number() over (order by num.Num desc) as TotalRank,
       rate.Rate as QuestionsInMay,
       num.Num as QuestionsTotal

from

(select count(PostId) as Rate, TagName
from
  Tags, PostTags, Posts
where Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId and Posts.Id = PostId
and Posts.CreationDate < '2010-06-01'
and Posts.CreationDate > '2010-05-01'
group by TagName) as rate

INNER JOIN

(select count(PostId) as Num, TagName
from
  Tags, PostTags, Posts
where Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId and Posts.Id = PostId
group by TagName
having count(PostId) > 800)
as num ON rate.TagName = num.TagName
order by rate.rate desc
;
```